# inserting multiple checkboxes into MySQL (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dao

I'm currently working on a school project and i'm trying to upload a "post" of a recipe. this includes image, title, instructions,ingredients and also 1 or multiple categories.
all of them insert fine and well. the only issue is with the categories. It only inserts 1 category even if I select multiple checkboxes.
It's supossed to insert every checkbox into a new row in the database.

My DAO

```php
public function insertCategory($data, $title) {
    
  if (empty($errors)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `recipes_categories` (`category_id`, `recipe_id`) VALUES(:category_id,:recipe_id);";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':category_id', $data['category_id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':recipe_id', $title['id']);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      return $this->selectcategoryById($this->pdo->lastInsertId());
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

My Controller (relevant parts)

```php
public function upload() {
    
    
  // variabele om foutmelding bij te houden
  $error = '';

  // controleer of er iets in de $_POST zit
  if(!empty($_POST['action'])){
    // controleer of het wel om het juiste formulier gaat
    if($_POST['action'] == 'add-image') {
      // controleren of er een bestand werd geselecteerd
      if (empty($_FILES['image']) || !empty($_FILES['image']['error'])) {
        $error = 'Gelieve een bestand te selecteren';
      }

      if(empty($error)){
          // controleer of het een afbeelding is van het type jpg, png of gif
          $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');
          if(!in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $whitelist_type)){
              $error = 'Gelieve een jpeg, png of gif te selecteren';
          }
        }

        if(empty($error)){
        // controleer de afmetingen van het bestand: pas deze gerust aan voor je eigen project
        // width: 270
        // height: 480
        $size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        if ($size[0] < 100 || $size[1] < 100) {
            $error = 'De afbeelding moet minimum 100x100 pixels groot zijn';
        }
      }

      if(empty($error)){
        // map met een random naam aanmaken voor de upload: redelijk zeker dat er geen conflict is met andere uploads
        $projectFolder = realpath(__DIR__);
        $targetFolder = $projectFolder . '/../assets/ads';
        $targetFolder = tempnam($targetFolder, '');
        unlink($targetFolder);
        mkdir($targetFolder, 0777, true);
        $targetFileName = $targetFolder . '/' . $_FILES['image']['name'];

        // via de functie _resizeAndCrop() de afbeelding croppen en resizen tot de gevraagde afmeting
        // pas gerust aan in je eigen project
        $this->_resizeAndCrop($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $targetFileName, 100, 100);
        $relativeFileName = substr($targetFileName, 1 + strlen($projectFolder));
        $data = array(
            'image' => $relativeFileName,
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'instructions' => $_POST['stappenplan'],
            'description' => $_POST['ingredienten'],
            'category_id' => $_POST['category'],
        );

        // TODO: schrijf de afbeelding weg naar de database op basis van de array $data

        if (!empty($_POST['action'])) {
          if ($_POST['action'] == 'add-image') {
            // array met data invullen
            $data = array(
              'path' => '/' . $relativeFileName,
              'title' => $_POST['title'],
              'instructions' => $_POST['stappenplan'],
              'description' => $_POST['ingredienten'],
              'category_id' => $_POST['category'],
            );
              
             // aanspreken van de DAO
             $insertImage = $this->uploadDAO->insertImage($data);

             $title = $this->uploadDAO->ImageInsterId($data);
             $this->set('title', $title);

             $ingredientsArray = explode( ',', $data['description'] );
             foreach($ingredientsArray as $ingredient){
               $insertIngredient = $this->uploadDAO->insertIngredients($ingredient , $title);
             }
             
             $insertCategory = $this->uploadDAO->insertCategory($data, $title);
   
        // TODO 2: zorg dat de variabele $error getoond wordt indien er iets fout gegaan is
          if (!$insertImage) {
            $errors = $this->uploadDAO->validate($data);
            $this->set('errors', $errors);
          } else {
            $_SESSION['info'] = 'Thank you for adding a Post!';
            header('Location: index.php?page=detail&id='. $title['id']);
            exit();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is some code here for the image upload too, but it isn't relevant since that is working.

My HTML

```html
    <span class="error"><?php if(!empty($error)){ echo $error;} ?></span>
    <section class="upload_box">
        <h1 class="hidden">upload-form</h1>
        <form method="post" action="index.php?page=upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form__box">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add-image" />
            <div class="form-field">
              <label class="upload__title form_container">Kies een afbeelding
              <span class="error"><?php if(!empty($errors['title'])){ echo $errors['title'];}?></span>
                  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" required  class="upload__button filter__submit input">
              </label>
              </div>
            <div class="form-field">
            <label class="upload__title form_container">Titel
              <span class="error"><?php
               if(!empty($errors['title'])){ 
                 echo $errors['title'];} ?></span>
              <input type="text" name="title" required  class="upload__title form_field input">
            </label>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-field"> 
                <label class="upload__title form_container">Stappenplan
                  <span class="error"><?php if(!empty($errors['instructions'])){ echo $errors['instructions'];} ?></span>
                  <textarea name="stappenplan" id="stappenplan" cols="50" rows="5" required  class="form_field upload__title input"></textarea>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-field"> 
              
              <label class="upload__title form_container">Ingredienten
              <span class="error"><?php if(!empty($errors['description'])){ echo $errors['description '];} ?></span>
              <input type="text" TextMode="MultiLine" name="ingredienten" maxlength="255" required  class="form_field upload__title input"  id="ingredienten">
            </label>
            </div>
          
            <div class="category_container">
              <label class="category_label filter__button">
              <input class="category_input" type="checkbox" id="pasta" name="category" value="1">
              Pasta</label>

              <label class="category_label filter__button">
              <input class="category_input" type="checkbox" id="veggie" name="category" value="2">
              Veggie</label>

              <label class="category_label filter__button">
              <input class="category_input" type="checkbox" id="vlees" name="category" value="3">
              Vlees</label>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-field">
              <input type="submit" value="uploaden"  class="filter__button filter__submit">
              <input type="reset" value="wissen"  class="filter__button filter__submit">
            </div> 
          </form>
    </section>

<script src="js/validate.js"></script>
```

What I do know:
I know the recipe_id isn't an issue. I use the same for other SQL inserts.
I don't want an `explode()` or `implode()` as they don't work in this case.
Tried several foreaches but haven't gotten it to work, just yet.
it's also nothing to do with brackets or comma's or whatever.

**It's just the insert only doing it once while I have 2 checkbox values. and I don't know how to make it loop over both or all 3 when all 3 are selected**

Answer (score -1):

```
             <div class="category_container">
              <label class="category_label filter__button">
              <input class="category_input" type="checkbox" id="pasta" name="category[]" value="1">
              Pasta</label>

              <label class="category_label filter__button">
              <input class="category_input" type="checkbox" id="veggie" name="category[]" value="2">
              Veggie</label>

              <label class="category_label filter__button">
              <input class="category_input" type="checkbox" id="vlees" name="category[]" value="3">
              Vlees</label>
            </div>
```

You need to use `category[]`, rather than just `category` to send multiple values in form submit.

Now, you can fetch the values of categories

```
$categories = (is_array($_POST['category'])) ? $_POST['category'] : [];
```

I have assigned categories a default value if there is no checkbox selected.

Then use implode function of php:

```
$categories_string = implode(',', $categories);
```

or use a foreach loop based on how you want to save in your database table:

```
foreach ($category as $category)
{
  //use each category
}
```